# R make lots of text files

Tags: r, text, write.table, sink

Sample

```
x <- 1:10
fileConn<-file("file[x.txt")
writeLines("hello number",
           print(x), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Here what I have is x which goes from 1 thru 10.
I wish to make 10 files called "file1.txt" thru "file10.txt" that says

```
"hello number"
1
```

thru

```
"hello number"
10
```

for example.

edit- it should actually be

```
hello number 1
```

instead of

```
hello number
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try using an `apply` function here:

```
sapply(x, function(y) {
    name <- paste0("file", y, ".txt")
    fileConn <- file(name)
    writeLines(c("hello number", y), fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
})
```

If you don't want those default line breaks, then one option is to just call `writeLines` with a single character:

```
writeLines(paste0("hello number ", y), fileConn)
```

Comment: This is bringing error:  Error in writeLines("hello number\n", print(y), fileConn) : 
  'con' is not a connection

Comment: @bvowe I think your call to `writeLines` was incorrect, and I copied it.  Try my updated answer, which passes a vector as the first argument.

Comment: thanks that is great actually please see my new edit about the line break removal thanks

Comment: @bvowe I edited my answer to cover this new requirement.  Note that it is generally rude to change your question after others have already answered.

Comment: I am real sorry. For next step should I make new question?

Comment: Yes, you should, unless it is a very minor change from this question.